# Android Device File Explorer save database to local disk

Tags: database, android-studio, save, local

I am using Android Studio 3.2.1 and I want to save database from emulator storage to my local disk. So I open device file explorer (DFE), select my database and click Save As. Everything is fine if I save small databases. If I try to save database more than 4 Mb,  device file explorer hangs on and it look like this:
[image]

And I can't save database to local disk. How can I fix it or it is only problem with my IDE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have faced same problem too. Newer version of Android Studio has this bug. 
The solution is adb command.
use this code inside Android Studio terminal:
adb exec-out run-as **your.package.name** cat databases/**your_db_name** > **your_db_name**
then goto your project directory such as:
C:\Users\your-PC\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication
now open the db file using any sqlite editor

Comment: Unfortunately, this solution does not work for me. I can't save large databases (or any large files) anyway.

Comment: send me the terminal screenshot where u have write the command

Comment: It was my mistake. Everything works like a charm! At least I could save database file more than 15 MB

Comment: Problem continue in new Android Studio 3.5.1. Device File Explorer "SaveAs" hangs for files > 384 KB

Answer (score 0):

Solved: The problem is in the Emulator SDK, specifically in the memory allocation of the Intel® HAXM ascelerator. The problem of Device File Explorer SaveAs was solved by increasing the memory, in my case, from 2Mb to 4Mb (the larger your file, you must give the ascelerator more memory)